# Методология БЭМ (html class)

Tags: классы, бэм

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="#" class="menu-link>
      <img src="img.png" class="menu-link__icon">  
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Будет ли правильно, если внутри блока `.menu-item` дочернему элементу наследую класс блока родителя `.menu`

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, по БЭМ правильно будет так:

```
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu__list">
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href=""></a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href=""></a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href=""></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: а если внутри тега a будут дочерние элементы

Comment: Не желательно в ссылку меню добавлять дочерние элементы. Если вам нужно картинка, лучше вставьте ее через `background-image` или с помощью псевдоэлементов `:before` и/или `"after`